# App crashes when trying to create a list of files from a directory

Tags: java, android, file

[I'm new here]
Hi, I'm trying to create a voice recorder app. I've already figured out how to record audio and play audio. Right now, I just want my app to display a list of all the files contained in a specific directory (for instance, "/Documents/MyApp"). So I can see the file I've just created. For now, I'm just trying to list any file coming from the external storage. The problem is, the app crashes on startup. When I remove the lines about reading external storage, it works perfectly.

I've tried a lot of differents methods online, all pretty similar. But they all leads to the same result : The app crashes on startup. Here's the code:

```java
public class FileAndDirectoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_and_directory);
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        File[] arrayFiles = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : arrayFiles){
            mNames.add(file.getName());
        }
        initRecyclerView();

    }
    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNames, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }
}
```

I expect the app to list, with the recycler view, the names of all the files contained in a directory. For that, I've created an `arrayList` called "mNames" getting all the names of the files before getting sent to my `RecyclerViewAdapter`. But the app crashes on startup...

Comment: Does your app have read permission on external storage?

Comment: **do post the crash log**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app is probably crashing because it can't complete **onCreate** (which MUST complete [per the Activity lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)) because you are not requesting permissions to view the storage.

You need to surround your code with a check that sees if the user has permission to user external storage. You also need to handle cases where the user does not grant permission. More documentation is [here](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting). Your code should be modified to look like this:

```
public class FileAndDirectoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST = 1000;
    private ArrayList<String> mNames = new ArrayList<>();
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_and_directory);
        //Check if we have the permission to read storage
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            //We dont have the permission, so request it.
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(thisActivity,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    PERMISSION_REQUEST);
        }
        //We already have permission
        else{
            permissionExists();
        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if(requestCode == PERMISSION_REQUEST){
            if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
                permissionExists();
            }
            else{
                //handle error
            }
        }
    }

    private void initRecyclerView() {
        RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerview);
        RecyclerViewAdapter adapter = new RecyclerViewAdapter(mNames, this);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    }

    private void permissionExists(){
        File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
        File[] arrayFiles = directory.listFiles();
        for (File file : arrayFiles) {
            mNames.add(file.getName());
        }
        initRecyclerView();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank. You. So. Much. It worked perfectly. I though only writing 'READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE' permission in the manifest file would do the trick. Again, thank you for responding to my question. Everything's ok now

Comment: Great, glad it worked. Please mark this as the answer to your question!

Answer (score 0):

Change your constructor like this ;

```
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_file_and_directory);
    File directory = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());
    File[] arrayFiles = directory.listFiles();
    for (File file : arrayFiles){
        mNames.add(file.getName());
    }
    mNames = arrayFiles== null
            ? new ArrayList<File>()
            : new ArrayList<File>(Arrays.asList(arrayFiles));

    initRecyclerView();

}
```

I'm not sure about  that it is going to solve your problem. Because we need to see logcat firstly. If your permissions are ok to see files, you need to initialize your ArrayList like this. I think this is your main problem. Hope this helps